# ffmpeg - fragmented mp4 takes long time to start playing on Chrome

Tags: amazon-s3, video

When using ffmpeg, to stream the output file to S3, it is required to use "-movflags frag_keyframe", and the generated file will be a fragmented mp4.

When I try to play this files from S3 it takes a long time to start playing. I have tried the recommended [movflags](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv) from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE) and all the possible combinations.

`ffmpeg -i https://notreal-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/video.mov -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://notreal-bucket/video/output.mp4`

Link of the file: https://happy-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stack-overflow/help.mp4

Edit:

I think it's not possible.

1) According to https://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html, the moov atom should be at the beginning of the file: "If the planned delivery method is progressive download or streaming (RTMP or HTTP), the moov atom will have to be moved to the beginning of the file. This ensures that the required movie information is downloaded first, enabling playback to start right away."

2) With ffmpeg writing directly to s3, the moov atom at the beginning will be empty.

3) With a fragmented video with empty moov atom, Chrome downloads the moof of each fragment before starting to play.

Comment: Please post a working link the the file.

Comment: @szatmary Thank you. I have added the link to the question.

Comment: The file is fine. Its not an ffmpeg problem. its an S3 or other infrastructure problem. Does S3 make the file available before it is complete? If not, you will need to upload individual fragments.

Comment: If your input is mp4 and the output is also mp4 then why bother with fragmenting? Only fragment if you want the file split into pieces (as .TS files) where the playlist for those individual pieces is an .M3U8 file.

Comment: @szatmary The file is "fine" but it takes a long time to start playing, which doesn't happen with non-fragmented mp4s. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "S3 making the file available before it is complete".

Comment: @VC.One The file has to be fragmented because ffmpeg is streaming to aws s3. Without fragmenting, ffmpeg outputs the following error: "muxer does not support non seekable output".

Comment: I think it's not possible.
1) According to https://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html, the moov atom should be at the beginning of the file. 
2) With ffmpeg writing directly to s3, the moov atom at the beginning will be empty. 
3) With a fragmented video with empty moov atom, Chrome downloads the moof of each fragment before starting to play.